# Cmnd F to Search on Page In Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, find

What I REALLY miss in Android Studio is the ability to search within a page without accessing the menu item "Edit/Find/Find" I simply want to use keys cmnd and f like I do in all other programs.  I was able to add it through my Mac preferences and now the key sequence shows next to the find, but it still does not work.

Anyone know how to "Find" within a single page with a keystroke combination in Android Studio.

Comment: Cmd-F is the default keybinding for Find in Android Studio, it is enabled by default and it works without any configuration. Do you maybe have some other utility program running that intercepts the shortcut globally?

Comment: In the off-chance you missed it, cmd + f doesn't open any dialog -- it just highlights/give focus to the search box.  Once you press cmd + f, just start typing.